# Using condensed fonts in Mobile apps

Tags: mobile, font, type

Any body have any experience using condensed fonts for mobile designs? Pro/Cons? They seem like they might be harder to read on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to avoid condensed fonts for that very reason (legibility on mobile), but that's not to say they won't work - they could still be legible and look good as heading fonts (IMO they don't really work as body copy fonts anyway). I would suggest just giving it a try in-browser and see what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are one of the harder aspects to grasp in responsive design but they're just as important as images and the grid, when it comes to a user friendly experience. Using something like the [Golden Ratio Type Calculator](http://www.pearsonified.com/typography/) in tandem with a media query allows you to very quickly morph things like your paragraph and header tags based on the size of the view portal.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    h2 { font-size: 17px}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    h2 { font-size: 15px}
}
```

Taking it a step further, you can also use *Modernizr.touch* to insert a body class and then automatically update all of your font definitions on a touch screen accordingly. A combination of both approaches is time consuming but gets the best results.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    h2 { font-size: 19px; font-family: "Arial Narrow";}
    body.touch h2 { font-size: 17px; font-family: "Open Sans";}
}
```